# Relacionar array de ids con colección en MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

**EDIT: Para quien ingrese a esta pregunta por la misma incidencia, quiero informarle que ambas soluciones ( Mauricio Contreras y Lean Szikora ) son correctas y llegan al mismo resultado, aunque se haga de manera diferente**

---

Estoy desarrollando un aplicativo en nodejs / express y MongoDB. Las consultas las realizo por medio de Mongoose. Tengo dos colecciones que deseo relacionar.

En la colección **apartamentos** tengo un array llamado **comodidades_elegidas**, que contiene los ids de los elementos previamente seleccionados de la colección **comodidades**.

En la colección **comodidades** está el atributo **subid_comodidad**, que es el coincide con el id presente en el array **comodidades_elegidas**

Deseo recorrer todos los elementos de la colección comodidades y compararla con los ids del array.
Los que coincidan, añadir el atributo **checked: 'checked'** y los que no coincidan añadir **checked: '/'**, además de conservar los demás atributos de la colección **comodidades**.

He dejado una muestra del resultado que deseo obtener en una variable.

**Resultado al consultar la colección comodidades con: find()**

```
console.log(comodidades_guardadas);
[
    {
    _id: 5f024df7ae24a433f8cd89b5,
    name: 'Salon Social',
    slug: 'salon-social',
    subid_comodidad: 14,
    __v: 0
    },
    {
    _id: 5f0259e93e70740f20ce8f43,
    name: 'Piscina',
    slug: 'piscina',
    subid_comodidad: 18,
    __v: 0
    },
    {
    _id: 5f0259ee3e70740f20ce8f44,
    name: 'Gimnasio',
    slug: 'gimnasio',
    subid_comodidad: 19,
    __v: 0
    },
    {
    _id: 5f0270225204522194c40554,
    name: 'Porteria',
    slug: 'porteria',
    subid_comodidad: 20,
    __v: 0
    }
]
```

**Array obtenido de la colección apartamentos**

```
console.log(apartamento.comodidades_elegidas);
[ '14', '18' ]
```

**Resultado que deseo obtener en una variable**

```
{
    array_resultado: [
    {
        _id: 5f024df7ae24a433f8cd89b5,
        name: 'Salon Social',
        slug: 'salon-social',
        subid_comodidad: 14,
        checked: 'checked'
    },
    {
        _id: 5f0259e93e70740f20ce8f43,
        name: 'Piscina',
        slug: 'piscina',
        subid_comodidad: 18,
        checked: 'checked'
    },
    {
        _id: 5f0259ee3e70740f20ce8f44,
        name: 'Gimnasio',
        slug: 'gimnasio',
        subid_comodidad: 19,
        checked: '/'
    },
    {
        _id: 5f0270225204522194c40554,
        name: 'Porteria',
        slug: 'porteria',
        subid_comodidad: 20,
        checked: '/'
    }
    ]
}
```

La información de cada consulta, la almaceno en variables. De ese modo la puedo procesar y enviar a la vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre que realices la operación una vez obtenidos los resultados y no como una consulta (sea mediante `query` o `aggregate`).

Si mal no entiendo tu planteamiento, tienes una colección llamada `apartamentos`, la cual contiene documentos que incluyen un campo tipo `Array`, el cual se compone de valores que coinciden con el campo `subid_comodidad` de documentos en la colección `comodidades`.

Al parecer se desea armar una lista que:

- Contenga todos los tipos de comodidades obtenidas de la colección `comodidades`.
- Cada comodidad de la lista debe tener un campo adicional llamado `checked`.
- El valor del campo adicional dependerá si el campo `subid_comodidad` coincide o no con un valor almacenado en el campo `comodidades_elegidas`.

Podrías armar una consulta de agregación (parecida a la que se plantea en la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371618/relacionar-array-de-ids-con-colecci%c3%b3n-en-mongodb/371729#371729) de @LeanSzikora).

O podrías hacer todo una vez obtenida la lista de todas las `comodidades`, ya que en teoría las comodidades serán las mismas para cada documento de la colección `apartamentos`.

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente lista de `comodidades_elegidas` en un documento de apartamentos, y tenemos la lista de comodidades, entonces podríamos hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente, una vez que hemos obtenido los datos desde la base de datos:

```js
const apartamento = { 
    _id: '5f04c505592b18b14afd0501',
    // ... , 
    comodidades_elegidas: [ 14, 18]
  };

const comodidades = [
  {
    _id: '5f024df7ae24a433f8cd89b5',
    name: 'Salon Social',
    slug: 'salon-social',
    subid_comodidad: 14,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5f0259e93e70740f20ce8f43',
    name: 'Piscina',
    slug: 'piscina',
    subid_comodidad: 18,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5f0259ee3e70740f20ce8f44',
    name: 'Gimnasio',
    slug: 'gimnasio',
    subid_comodidad: 19,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5f0270225204522194c40554',
    name: 'Porteria',
    slug: 'porteria',
    subid_comodidad: 20,
    __v: 0
  }
];

const resultado_array = comodidades.map(comodidad => {
  comodidad.checked = apartamento.comodidades_elegidas.includes(comodidad.subid_comodidad) ? 'checked' : '/';
  return comodidad;
});

console.log(resultado_array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Ahora bien, en tu pregunta, la lista de `comodidades_elegidas` la presentas como un `Array` de `Strings`:

```
comodidades_elegidas = ['14', '18'];
```

y en cambio el campo `subid_comodidad` en tu documento de comodidades es de tipo numérico.

Tendrías que tomar esto en cuenta a la hora de realizar la comparación. En mi respuesta he cambiado los tipos para que coincidan. Pero si recibes la lista con elementos de tipo cadena, basta con usar `toString()` al momento de hacer la comparación, por ejemplo:

```
apartamento.comodidades_elegidas.includes(comodidad.subid_comodidad.toString()) // <- uso toString() para convertir el tipo de numérico a cadena.
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Su solución es lo que buscaba, y con el ejemplo descrito funciona perfecto. Pero al aplicarlo a mi código, me apareció el siguiente error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()

La función principal es async y las consultas:

const apartamento = await Apartamento.findOne( { subid_apartamento: req.params.id });
const comodidades = await Comodidad.find()

Comment: Estás usando `await` sin envolver en un bloque `try/catch`. Seguramente hay algún error en la consulta y no está siendo capturado.

Comment: Así es tal cual la función:

gestionApartamentoCtrl.renderEditApartamentoForm = async (req, res) => {
    const apartamento = await Apartamento.findOne( { subid_apartamento: req.params.id } );
    const comodidades = await Comodidad.find()
    const resultado_array = comodidades.map(comodidad => {
        comodidad.checked = apartamento.comodidades_elegidas.includes(comodidad.subid_comodidad) ? 'checked' : '/';
        return comodidad; 
    });
    console.log(resultado_array);
    res.render('gestion/apartamento/edit-apartamento', {apartamento, comodidades})
};

Comment: Deberías tenerlo así: `gestionApartamentoCtrl.renderEditApartamentoForm = async (req, res) => {  try {const apartamento = await Apartamento.findOne({ subid_apartamento: req.params.id }); const comodidades = await Comodidad.find(); const resultado_array = comodidades.map(comodidad => {
    comodidad.checked = apartamento.comodidades_elegidas.includes(comodidad.subid_comodidad) ? 'checked' : '/'; return comodidad; }); console.log(resultado_array); res.render('gestion/apartamento/edit-apartamento', {apartamento, comodidades}) 
  } catch (error) { // manejo error } };`

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio por toda su ayuda, todo quedó funcionando bien y con su función logré cargar los input checkbox con el checked, según el array. Le he enviado un correo al Gmail que ví en su Github, por si quiere mantener el contacto conmigo, ya que ambos desarrollamos en el mismo entorno.

Answer (score 1):

creo que una consulta así podría servirte.

```
Comodidad.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "apartamentos",
        let: { id_comodidad: {$toString: "$subid_comodidad"}  },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $unwind: "$comodidades_elegidas"
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $eq: ["$comodidades_elegidas", "$$id_comodidad"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "checked"
    }
},
{
    $addFields: { checked: { $arrayElemAt: ["$checked", 0] } }
},
{
    $addFields: { checked: { $cond: [{"$toBool": "$checked"}, "checked", "/"] }}
}])
```

Paso explicar cada stage del pipeline:

1. Para la versión 3.6 en adelante Mongo te permite agregar un "subpipeline" que se va a aplicar a la colección a "joinear" [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) por lo tanto lo que hacemos aca es desarmar el array de comodidades que tiene el apartamento para luego matchear con los que tienen el sub_id del modelo de Comodidades. Todo esto lo guardamos en checked (en tipo array por la naturaleza del lookup).
2. Aplanamos el campo checked tomando su primer elemento. (Si el array checked es vacío deja el campo en undefined)
3. Verificamos su existencia reemplazando por lo que necesitabas que aparezca en el resultado.

Yo creo que se puede seguir iterando sobre esta primera idea, espero que te haya servido!

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder.

La consulta funciona bien en el sentido de que agrega el campo "checked", pero en todos devuelve " checked: '/', es decir un false.

Hay alguna manera de incorporar un if en el match, de manera que si el match es verdadero, el campo sea: checked: 'checked' y si el match da falso, el campo quede: checked: '/' ?

Comment: @andresf484 no noté que el array de comodidades_elegidas es de strings. Podés hacer una conversión con el stage $toString. Dejo la consulta que deberías hacer editada en mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias Lean, su solución también está correcta y la sugerencia del $toString si era lo que faltaba la primera vez. Finalmente decidí dejar el array como tipo Number en el modelo de mongoose, para prevenir el conflicto en este tipo de comparaciones. Su planteamiento con el aggregate (que no lo conocía antes), me va servir también para otras funciones en mi proyecto.